# Recursive Definition Where ∞ is an Element of a Subset of Integers. How can this be true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, infinity, recursion

I was recently provided the following True or False question:

```
Let S be a subset of the set of integers recursively defined by:
                Basis Step: 1 ∈ S
                Recursive Step: If x ∈ S, then x + 1 ∈ S.
```

```
True or False: ∞ ∈ S
```

I say false; however, I am being told by my professor it is true because,

> "The basis step begins at 1 and the recursive step simply adds 1. The
>   result of that addition is an element of set S. Then, 1 is added to
>   that result and the corresponding result is also an element of S. This
>   can go on all the way to infinity. This recursive definition is
>   essentially for the set of all positive integers."

What I don't understand is how infinity can be an element of a subset of integers given that infinity is not an integer. . .

Comment: Your professor is wrong.If he means that the set includes infinitely many numbers, that would be true, but $\infty \in S$ is false.

Comment: As written, your professor is Not Even Wrong; $\infty$ (as such) does not have a standard 'standalone' definition. There are many ways of defining an item called $\infty$, but for none of them is this statement true by definition. Are you sure this is _exactly_ what your professor wrote?

Comment: The claim is neither true nor false as long as $\infty$ has not been formally defined.

Comment: This is the verbatim quiz question and response feedback to my getting the question wrong for choosing "false"

Comment: One wonders how someone with such little understanding of mathematical induction could be employed as a mathematics professor.

Comment: *CS professor, actually. (And it shows in the attention to detail)

Comment: Every positive integer is in this set, and this set is infinite, but every member of the set is a finite number; there is nothing called $\infty$ that belongs to this set unless $\infty$ is some finite number. The professor is quite wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual meaning attached to the symbol $\infty$, the claim is obviously false because

$$\infty\notin\mathbb Z$$ so that $$\infty\notin S\subset\mathbb Z.$$

With what you write in the title, the claim is obviously true because "$\infty$ is an Element of a Subset of Integers" is another way to write

$$\infty\in S.$$

In both cases, the recursive definition of $S$ is strictly of no use.

Comment: I wrote the title based on the problem at hand... the title is of my own making and wasn't something provided by the professor

Comment: @AntonRasmussen: I suspected this. Anyway, what you wrote is lacking rigor and has no truth value.

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna send a "can I get my points back?" email. I wanted to be wrong on this because this would be the fifth(!) email I've had to write pointing out mathematical errors that make the claimed correct answer to a quiz actually incorrect. He's given all points back so far ... still, I miss taking math classes under the math department and not the CS department!

Comment: @AntonRasmussen: as the claim is neither false nor true, he must give back the points and keep them.

Comment: Or, you know, throw out the question entirely? Thanks for your help on this by the way.